# java program for sorting and returning arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

so the code I am working on looks like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadStrings{
public static String main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("input3.txt"));
String [] array = new String[100];
int nextSpot = 0;

while( in.hasNext()){
  array[nextSpot++] = in.next();
}
//use the sort function
selectionSort(array, nextSpot);
//print the results

}



public static void selectionSort(String [] array, int nextSpot){
  String tmp;
  for (int i = 0; i < nextSpot; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nextSpot; j++) {
      if( array[i].equals(array[j])){
        tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Assuming the text file exists is there something wrong with my code?
I also dont know how to print the resulting array

Comment: What's the issue? Does the code work? If not, what problem are you facing? What did you try to resolve it?

Comment: I do not know how to print the result after selectionSort is called

Comment: You can just iterate over your array, and print each element in your main method. BTW, I don't see how your selection sort going to work. You are using `equals` method instead of `compareTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **not clear**. I assume that you want to print the result to the file itself. You can use `BufferedWriter` class like this:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("input3.txt")));
```

and use it's `write()` method to print the array.

You might want to check your [selectionSort()](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/31arrayselectionsort.html) though.